# On which disk device Ubuntu has been installed?

Tags: installation, disk-management

I've chosen 'Something else' for the installation type so as to designate the disk partition (device) that I want to install Ubuntu. After installation is completed, I'm not sure that I've selected the partition I want. Is there a way to check which disk partition Ubuntu has been installed on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
  sudo fdisk -l
```

and that should tell you the answer.

This will list the partitions and devices on your system. If your system only had one hard disk, look for `/dev/sda`.

You may get something like:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 698.5 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000sdfss

Device    Boot      Start        End    Blocks  Id System
/dev/sda1 *          2048  195311615  97654784  83 Linux
/dev/sda2       195311616  400111615 102400000  83 Linux
/dev/sda3       400111616  522991615  61440000  83 Linux
/dev/sda4       536815616 1465147391 464165888   5 Extended
/dev/sda5       654030848 1413199871 379584512  83 Linux
/dev/sda6       536817664  654028799  58605568  83 Linux
/dev/sda7      1439174656 1465147391  12986368  82 Linux swap / Solaris
```

Look for `Linux` systems, as well as the `swap` partitions and the one(s) with the `Boot` flag.

If you have problems understanding it post the full output here and I'll explain what it means.

Comment: What about *'run this: `sudo fdisk -l`'*?

Comment: @wilf Yup, that runs `fdisk` as `root`.

Comment: @Wolfer thanks a lot, Ubuntu is on the place I want.

Comment: @user236571 - in that case mark it as answered then ;-)